# How to turn off cors for development in jhipster/Vue

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, vue.js, cors

I am updating my old question.

I have a jhipster application with spring boot and vue. When I am trying to make a request from my vue frontend project I am getting the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/downloader/' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried setting my origin from the application.dev.yml like this:

```
 cors:
    # Allow Ionic for JHipster by default (* no longer allowed in Spring Boot 2.4+)
    allowed-origins: 'http://localhost:9000'
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-headers: '*'
    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-alert,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-error,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-params'
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

I only changed the alowed-origins part. But I am still getting this error. Then I tried the following inside the SecurityConfigurationClass:

```
    .antMatchers("/api/downloader").permitAll()
```

I thought this maybe would allow the requests but it did not help. Can someone maybe help me out? How should I fix this error? Even if I start it with production profile where cors is disabled it still gives me the same error. Is it something I have to fix from the frontend side? Because login or something else works.

Comment: instead of commenting it out, you should try to edit the config to allow your request origin. CORS on default blocks pretty much everything.

Comment: I tried to add my origin (localhost:9000) in my controller with @CrossOrigin and in the config file adding my origin to be allowed I tried even wildcard * and still no luck. I tried to change the securityconfiguration to allow my origin but still nothing helped

Comment: did you restart your server after changes? Had that myself, wondering why nothing happens. CORS changes are mostly not updated on hot reload

Comment: if you are using spring boot, you can just use `@CrossOrigin` annotation on your controller

Comment: I did it but szill no luck That was my first try to fix this error

Comment: So is there no one who can help? I am still stuck with this nothing I try helps

Comment: Did you generate the api endpoint you would like to access via jhipster? So is that an entity created with jhispter?

Comment: No I did it manually.

Comment: I found that the autogenerated code (JHipster 7.0.1) may not be correct. In the WebConfigurer there is a method that creates a CorsFilter but it should create a CorsConfigurationSource  instead.
Also in the SecurityConfiguration you have to enable cors(withDefaults()).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.5/reference/html5/#cors

I hope this will work for you as well.